# magento2 - homepage blank with 'Search' keyword

Tags: magento2

Why is my frontend showing this:

[image]

Which seems to come from 
**Magento\Search\view\frontend\templates\form.mini.phtml**

I have not changed any core files

Comment: What were you doing?  Which theme are you using (Luma or your own?)  Is this a new install?

Comment: Same default luma